# How can I check whether the Google Instant Apps feature is enabled in a phone before using it?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have two projects with me. My idea is to open one app inside the life cycle of another application itself. I was successful in achieving that using the Instant Apps feature by calling the intent to the link to that child app's activity and used App Link Intents.

I used this code to send intent to the instant app

```
String url = "https://example.instantappsample.com/main";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

The variable `url` contains the link which is caught by the app link assistant and opens the specific activity of the child activity.

But the application which I am using through my parent application can only run if the Google Instant Apps feature is enabled in the phone.
If the feature isn't enabled it shall be opening in the browser where it shall show an error since no page is assigned to the specified URL.

How can I prompt the user to enable the Instant Apps feature if its not in the Google Settings in order to further proceed with the app flow?

Answer (score 1):

To check if IA is enabled in settings, perform the following action:

```
InstantAppsClient client = InstantApps.getInstantAppsClient(context);
 Task<Boolean> iAEnableTask = client.areInstantAppsEnabledForDevice();
 iAEnableTask
     .addOnCompleteListener(iAEnableTask -> performAction(iAEnableTask.getResult()))
     .addOnFailureListener(exception -> handleException(exception));
```

where performAction is the method where you ask the user to enable IA in the settings if the returned boolean result is false.

The references are here:    [check for IA enabled](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantAppsClient)  [IA url launcher](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/Launcher)

You can then adjust your flow as needed.